# Laravel request merge by name

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `User` model with a lot of attributes, and I have split lot of them to separate tables with different relationships. When creating a new user, I'd like it all to be done on one page, also updating related models.

The way it works now is by filtering requests in controller and making an adequate model by selecting fields which are relevant for that model:

```
User::create($request->only('x', 'y', 'z');
```

While this works, it looks ugly, and I am looking for a more slick solution, so I was wondering if it is possible to group requests in front end somehow? For example:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('merged.x','',null,array('class' => 'grey')) }}
{{ Form::checkbox('merged.y','',null,array('class' => 'grey')) }}
```

so that I would get both of those attributes under `merged` attribute in request JSON

```
merged:{
    x : value_x
    y : value_y
}
```

So that I could ultimately make

```
User::create($request->merged);
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want, but can't you just call the checkboxes `merged[]` and set their appropriate values to get the right ones?

Comment: checkboxes are just an example, there are a lot of input fields, text, date etc...so it wouldn't work like that

Comment: Works for other input fields as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<form action="/form-array" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <input type="text" name="profile[name]">
    <input type="text" name="profile[email]">
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

and if you dump this request:

```
Route::post('/form-array', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) 
{
   dd($request->all(), $request->get('profile'));
});
```

you get your desired result:
[image]